# function stops running if "console.log()" removed from code

Tags: javascript, events, console.log, audiocontext

I encountered this problem few times in different situations.

when I have `console.log('something')` inside a function, everything works perfect(at least it seems perfect).

when I comment out `console.log('something')`
it still works but not every time.

is it some kind of bug?
ex:

```
var object=0
function run()
{
    console.log("text")//<---this one makes it work
    console.log()//<---not the empty one one

    object=new Object()
    object.buffer=getBuffer()
    ..other functions
    object.onended=function()
    {
         run()
         ..other functions
    }
    object.start()
}
run()
```

So this will stop after a while if `console.log("text")` is removed. and without `console.log()` line I don't see a way to find a reason. Maybe there is another way?

sure I could let this line be there and let it output some "!" or something. But it feels wrong. Like fixing a tire with duct tape:)

if it helps:
`object` in this case is `AudioBufferSourceNode`.
for some reason it cannot be started more than once so it has to be redefined if you want to play next audio track.

I searched for an answer but I failed. So this is actually my first time asking about programming in a forum.  So correct me if I express myself badly. And thank you for your time.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Have you tried debuging the function?

Comment: yes I tried debugging with console.log() and when I have it inside a function it works and I can't find anything strange. So I remove console.log() from a function and after a while "onended" event ether does not occur or the function assigned to this event does not start.

Comment: All arguments in JavaScript functions are optional (read "loosely typed"). So I don't see any reasons for this behavior. provide the complete program you are trying to run so that we can also have a look at it locally . And also there are some issues in browser IE < 8.

Comment: What if you debug in for instance in Chromes developmer tools?

Comment: I use Chrome mostly and I tried development tools. IE does not support audioContext... Anyway, now I tried to run it on another machine and it worked just fine! Still it means that some people will not be able to run it?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and have no idea what's wrong. As soon as I remove the `console.log('.')`, my function stops working

Comment: Same issue! I had a function that triggers on jQuery document ready, that mostly wasn't executing (though sporadically, it would, or it would very delayed). I added a console.log statement so I could see when document ready was firing, and then suddenly the function worked consistently. Remove the console.log(), stopped working; added it, worked perfectly again. Makes no sense!